Maui DrawingView last version crash on iOS
I have a probleme with Maui DrawingView since last update of MAUI and MAUI Community toolkit.
My app crash when a page with a DrawingView are started, the following error is throwed :
Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.XamlParseException: 'Position 20:30. No parameterless constructor defined for type 'CommunityToolkit.Maui.Views.DrawingView'.'
But when I put the DrawingView from code behind it's work, this error occured only on ios.
Somebody can help me ?
Thanks a lot

Just downgrade for the time being or raise a bug with the CommunityToolkit team and see if they respond to it with something

Doesn't sound like a programming question if some app from somebody else crashes on you?

Hi @delewrocks, how can we reproduce this problem? Could you please post the steps of reproducing this problem or some code snippets so that we can test on our side?

I have resolve the problem if I init an DrawingView object in the contructor of the contentpage.

Hi @delewrocks, thanks for your support and feedback. As a summary, I will post your solution as an answer so that it will help others who have similar problems. :)


Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.XamlParseException: 'Position 20:30. No
parameterless constructor defined for type
'CommunityToolkit.Maui.Views.DrawingView'.'

From the log above, we could know that the constructor of DrawingView has no arguments. So, you can initialize a DrawingView object in the constructor of the ContentPage.
